# R shiny reactivity to trigger only if both inputs changed

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a relatively simple app with two radioGroupButtons

```
radioGroupButtons('rng1', label = 'Select metric',
                                                     choices = c('A', 'B', 'C' ),
                                                     selected = 'A', justified = TRUE)

radioGroupButtons('rng2', label = 'Select metric',
                                                     choices = c('A', 'B', 'C' ),
                                                     selected = 'A', justified = TRUE)
```

I was trying to build a reactivity around observe() or observeEvent() where the reactivity is triggered only when both have changed but it doesn't work.

So in an example such as below (tried many others)

```
    observe({
      req(input$rng1, input$rng2)
      print('both changed')
    })
```

this triggers when only 1 changes. I need it to print only when both values were changed.

I believe there must be a very basic solution but am unable to find it.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use `reactiveValues` as initial values in the `radioGroupButtons` which are set to `A` and then compare it

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    radioGroupButtons('rng1', label = 'Select metric',choices = c('A', 'B', 'C' ),selected = 'A', justified = TRUE),
    radioGroupButtons('rng2', label = 'Select metric',choices = c('A', 'B', 'C' ),selected = 'A', justified = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    v <- reactiveValues(rng1 = "A",rng2 = "A")    

    observeEvent(c(input$rng1,input$rng2),{
        req(input$rng1 != v$rng1,input$rng2 != v$rng2)
        print('both changed')

        v$rng1 <- input$rng1
        v$rng2 <- input$rng2
    },ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Looks great. I didn't know you can put a condition inside req. In help the only examples are req(x).

Comment: Using your code, is there any way to identify what inputs were changed?. I mean, i have hundreds of inputs and not sure if checking one by one is the most efficient way