# Shiny - How to get the value of the last pushed radiobutton?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive

I have 5 radiobuttons with the choices "yes" and "no".
I want a modalDialog to popup only if you select "no" on the radiobutton.
I tried to solve it with a if statement, but the logic doesn't work, because if "buttonAbluf1" is no and after that the "buttonAbluf2" is pushed to yes, the modalDialog pops up:

```
    if(isTRUE(input$buttonAbluf1=="No" ||
        input$buttonAbluf2 =="No" ||
        input$buttonAbluf3 =="No" ||
        input$buttonAbluf4 =="No" ||
        input$buttonAbluf5 =="No"))
    {
                         
                         showModal(popup())
                       }
    popup <- function(){
        modalDialog(easyClose = F,
          textAreaInput("com", "Bemerkung:", width = "750px", heigh = "200px"),
          
          size = "l",  
          
        )
        
      }
```

How could I define the logic, that it only pops up if you select "no", regardless the selection on the other radiobuttons?
I thought about getting the value of the last pushed button. If this value is no the modalDialog could be shown.

Comment: a fully working minimal code example would be helpful here, so that one can recreate your issue

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770360/13513328

Answer (score 0):

This is what observeEvent is for:

```
observeEvent(input$buttonAbluf1,{
        if(input$buttonAbluf1=='No'){
           showModal(popup())
        }
    })
```

As all you buttons should behave the same, you can also wrap them all in one for-loop:

```
for(i in c(1:5)){
    local({
        i=i
        observeEvent(input[[paste0('buttonAbluf',i)]],{
            if(input[[paste0('buttonAbluf',i)]]=='No'){
                showModal(popup())
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! It works - thanks a lot!!

Comment: As mentioned above, fully working minimal examples help ensuring fully functioning code. Also, if the issue is solved for you make sure to accept the most helpful answer